# VSCode Python interactive terminal scroll wheel is broken and does not show new output correctly

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ipython

I have been using VSCode's interactive terminal for Python for a while and a recent version change seems to have broken the scroll wheel and output.

For example, when sending code from the file to the terminal it works as expected:
[image]

However, when entering new commands in the interactive terminal directly it clips the output
[image]

The scroll wheel to the right in the interactive terminal no longer scrolls although I can navigate through output cells using the arrow keys

**I strongly suspect this is a settings issue but have not been able to find the right config.**

Any help would be much appreciated!

---

I have tried reinstalling, switching environments, and searching for others with a related problem although nothing has worked.

Comment: it looks like UI issue with the new release ! Nothing to do with python

Comment: Maybe try downgrading to the previous version

Comment: have you used the DevTools to see if the text is really there and it is just a CSS issue

Comment: Thanks for all the great suggestions! 

@ShekharSamanta - did you find this documented / mentioned anywhere else?

Comment: @Amer - thanks I will try this now, my understanding was VSCode made it challenging to downgrade but it looks like there is a workaround

Comment: @rioV8 - the text is there it is a CSS / formatting issue as when I enter another command it shows the previous command's output

Comment: then see if it also is still in the Insiders build of VSC, if so create an issue if not already done, if it is not a VSC issue they will move the issue to the vscode-python repo

Comment: @gibbsbravo Did you find a solution to this issue? I have the same issue and can't figure out how to solve it. I've played with the autoscroll settings (in addition to the options you mention in the first post) but that does not seem to work.

Comment: @Olivier - Hey sorry forgot to post the solution - I tried a lot of different things and unfortunately had to revert back to an old version, I am temporarily using the November 2021 VS Code release (version 1.63) and October Jupyter VSCode extension (v2021.10.1001413611)